# How to display an error page for static files when using existingResponse="PassThrough" in IIS 7

Tags: iis, umbraco, custom-error-pages

To be able to get my application (Umbraco CMS) to handle 404 errors, I need to have following setting in my web.config:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

It works well for displaying a custom 404 error page from Umbraco, but it doesn't work for displaying a 404 error page when a static file cant be found.

For example http://www.example.com/non-existing-file.png returns a 404 status code, but respons is blank. That fits with this description of the PassThrough mode:

> PassThrough – If existingResponse is seen as “PassThrough”, custom
>   error module will always pass through responses from modules. This
>   setting will make custom error module return blank response if modules
>   don’t set any text.
>   (http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2008/02/18/what-to-expect-from-iis7-custom-error-module.aspx)

What is the "custom error module"? And how do I get it to return a non blank response?

**Update**

After stepping through the request handling routines in Umbraco (with a debugger), I have a better understanding of the problem space. As written in the citation above, when existingResponse="PassThrough" then all handling of http errors is done in the custom modules. So to answer my own question, a "custom error module" is in this instance the "UmbracoModule".

One way to solve this problem would be to create a new custom module that will check for the existence of the  static files on the disk. It can be done quite nice, I read the list of static files from IIS and read the configuration of customErrors or httpErrors elements from the web.config to get a custom error page. But I kind of think this is crude solution. I would much rather pass the responsibility back to IIS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. For the benefit of anyone else looking for help with this, here's some extra information on 404 handling.

- [Old Umbraco wiki page](https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/configuring-404-pages) - describes your solution using the file  /config/umbracoSettings.config
- [404 for files](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/58066-404-for-files) - works for Umbraco 7 and describes the use of the tag <httpErrors/>
- [IIS version 6 fix](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/8244-IIS7-404) - fixing on IIS6 and how it compares with IIS7